# Constructing a parallelepiped with all faces having equal diagonals, what goes wrong?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, solution-verification, systems-of-equations, question-verification

I'm trying to construct a parallelepiped where each face has diagonal lengths $d_1$ and $d_2$. I start by constructing a parallelogram in the $x,y$ -plane that has the correct diagonals. I put that it has side vectors $(a, 0, 0)$ and $(b1, b2, 0)$ where

$$ \begin{align}
b_1 &= \frac{d_2^2-d_1^2}{4a} \\
b_2 &= \frac{1}{4a}\sqrt{(d_2^2+d_1^2)a^2-16a^4-(d_2^2-d_1^2)^2}
\end{align}$$

and $a$ is a free parameter (restricted to an interval). This seems to work according to [this Desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5irokw9wuw).

Then let the third side vector be $(c_1, c_2, c_3)$. From the diagonal lengths we get the following equations

$$\begin{align}
(c_1+a)^2 + c_2^2 + c_3^2 &= d_2^2 \\
(c_1-a)^2 + c_2^2 + c_3^2 &= d_1^2 \\
(c_1+a)^2 + (c_2+b_2)^2 + c_3^2 &= d_2^2 \\
(c_1-a)^2 + (c_2-b_2)^2 + c_3^2 &= d_1^2
\end{align}$$

And solving them (subtract the top two to get $c1$ and then the bottom two to get $c_2$) I get

$$\begin{align}
c_1 &= b_1\\
c_2 &= \frac{d_2^2-d_1^2 - 4b_1^2}{4b_2} \\
c_3 &= \sqrt{d_1^2-(c_1-a)^2-c_2^2}
\end{align}$$

But then we also need to satisfy $(c_1+a)^2 + (c_2+b_2)^2 + c_3^2 = d_2^2$ with this $c_3$ and get the enormous equation for $a$

$$
\frac{d_2^2-d_1^2}{2} - \frac{(d_2^2-d_1^2)^2}{8a^2} + \frac{1}{16a^2}(8(d_2^2+d_1^2)a^2-16a^4-(d_2^2-d_1^2)^2) = 0
$$
That is a quadratic in $a^2$ and in the end we get only one (or possibly $4$) working $a$. Is this correct?

(At first I didn't realize that we still need to check for satisfying the bottom equations and not any $a$ will actually work, but now as to use the only correct working $a$ it seems to go through. But I'm too lazy to solve the equation and I'm posting this anyhow.)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to show that all faces of the parallelepiped are congruent rhombi.

Consider a vertex of the parallelepiped where the equal diagonals meet (there are two such vertices). Let the edges be $a,b,c$ with $\gamma,\alpha,\beta$ being the respective angles between the pairs of the edges at the vertex.

Then we have the following system of equations:
$$
a^2+b^2+2ab\cos\gamma=d_1^2,\quad a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\gamma=d_2^2,\\
b^2+c^2+2bc\cos\alpha=d_1^2,\quad b^2+c^2-2bc\cos\alpha=d_2^2,\\
c^2+a^2+2ca\cos\beta=d_1^2,\quad c^2+a^2-2ca\cos\beta=d_2^2.\\
$$

This implies $$a^2+b^2=b^2+c^2=c^2+a^2=\frac{d_1^2+d_2^2}2\implies a=b=c
=\frac{\sqrt{d_1^2+d_2^2}}2$$
and
$$
\alpha=\beta=\gamma=2\arctan\frac{d_2}{d_1}.
%\tan\frac\alpha2=\tan\frac\beta2=\tan\frac\gamma2=\frac{d_2}{d_1}.
$$

From the last equation it follows that the parallelepiped exists only if $\displaystyle\frac{d_2}{d_1}<\sqrt3$.

Comment: Thanks! Why the last restriction though? Doesn't for example the parallelepiped spanned by $(0.5\sqrt{10}, 0, 0)$, $(0.4\sqrt{10}, 0.3\sqrt{10}, 0)$ and $(0.4\sqrt{10}, \frac{2}{15}\sqrt{10}, 0.849836585598798)$ have $d_1=1$ and $d_2=3$?

Comment: With your data I obtained $d_1=3$ and $d_2=1$. Note that $d_1$ in my solution is the diagonal three instances of which have a common vertex, so there is no symmetry between $d_1$ and $d_2$.

Comment: Oh right, should've realized that. I had them other way around.